# How to extract part of a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string which is converted from date to string and the data looks like this: `6/2/2010 4:30:00 PM6/2/2010 4:45:00 PM` and I need output like this: `04:30PM`. Could you please help?

Comment: The string contains two dates like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.ToString("hh:mmtt")` should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime.ToString("")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to format the output.  See [these samples](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DateTime.ToShortTimeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring(v=VS.100).aspx) method. Note that the output format is based on the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) set for the calling thread.

Comment: This will put a space between the time and the AM/PM.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the input with `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.TryParse()` and use the format options of `DateTime.ToString()` as with [spoulson's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957794/how-to-extract-part-of-the-string/2957810#2957810).

Answer (score 0):

Specifically:

```
x.ToString("hh:mmtt")
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string orig = "6/2/2010 4:30:00 PM6/2/2010 4:45:00 PM"
string first = orig.Substring(0, orig.IndexOf("M") + 1);
DateTime firstDate = DateTime.ParseExact(first, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null);
string firstTime = firstDate.ToString("hh:mmtt");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2010,2,6,16,30,00);
date.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: Didn't have a compiler here, so did it out of my head. Doesn't change the fact that the new DateTime was just an illustration how to use the DateTime structure. aparnakarthik already had a Date (DateTime?) object and changed it to string. He should not do that and use the ToString on the DateTime object.